# Unable to maintain weights and increase in reps from work out session to session, why?

Tags: strength, strength-training, reps, muscle-endurance

I train everyday except wednesday and sunday (I only do abs).

- Monday: legs
- Tuesday: chest & calves & lateral delts
- Thursday: back &
  calves & back delts
- Friday: delts & trapezes
- Saturday: arms & calves

I do it for 3 or 4 weeks. And I didn't notice real increase in the number of reps I do.

More important: last week I could dumbells bench with 57lbs (26kg) per hand in 10 reps (forcing last two reps by pausing at the maximum of the contraction), for 5 series. This week, triceps were too sollicited: I had to decrease my weights to 20kg (48,5lbs) with the same number of reps and series.

I do 8-12reps. If I can't do 12reps, I try to do forced reps (by pausing at the maximum of contraction or flexion, depending on the exercise) and/or (depending on the exercise) I continue the serie with 65% of the weight.

So I really work out hard.

Comment: I imagine you have trouble maintaining weight because your workout routine is rather worthless.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you my friend

Comment: @UnbescholtenerBuerger nevermind, but *"your workout routine is ********"* is as far from constructive as can be. It'd be great if you could at least give the OP some hints what to look for.

Comment: @PaulK, in his other questions he received constructive hints galore, from myself included. But instead of trying what everyone is suggesting over and over, namely sticking to an established beginner routine, he decides to come up with a weekly routine that has one back day opposed to three calf days. So maybe someone needs to tell him bluntly that this is completely worthless.

Comment: @UnbescholtenerBuerger - I understand your position, however please remember that we do have a "Be Nice" policy, and possibly younger members as well. You can be blunt without being unnecessarily earthy.

Comment: @JohnP , fair enough, I try to be nicer when being blunt next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As has been pointed out, you have been coming up with routines that are of questionable quality, pursuing them for a very short time and then wondering why you are not getting results.

Building muscle/fitness takes time, lots of time, with attention to rest, diet and consistency on a well thought out program.

I would recommend you do the following things:

- Scrap your current routine
- Pick an established routine such as [Starting Strength](https://startingstrength.com/), [Stronglifts 5x5](https://stronglifts.com/5x5/), Wendler 5/3/1, etc. and start following it
- Keep a training diary to chart progress
- Keep a food diary to make sure you are eating enough of the right foods
- Rest when told to. Resist the urge to add more because you feel good today.
- Train for at least 4-6 months before assessing progress.

If you can follow those steps, you will progress. Especially for beginners, weightlifting and seeing improvements is not rocket science. It's all been done before, many times, and there are a lot of good programs that work if you pay attention to the details.

Answer (score 2):

Not addressing the workout routine, but 3 to 4 weeks seems like a short amount of time to be looking for a real increase in reps. Your form will improve and that will take more strength and maybe cut down on additional reps.
Also, dropping 8.5 pounds  is no big deal... you could have pushed yourself too much in a previous workout and not fully recovered.... 
Quit using all this energy worrying about numbers and just work your muscles to exhaustion.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW: I think @JohnP's answer is likely the best advice you'll get. Start with a new and proven program and go from there. His recommendations are also spot on.

---

This is my specific opinion on your current regime:

```
Monday:    legs  
Tuesday:   chest & calves & lateral delts  
Wednesday: Rest or abs(?)  
Thursday:  back & calves & back delts  
Friday:    delts & trapezes  
Saturday:  arms & calves  
Sunday:    Rest or abs(?)
```

Is this a bad program? No, but it has multiple flaws. I say that because it is incredibly similar to the layout I'm using for my own training right now, however, I'm seeing a continual increase in strength. I've been doing it for a year (read: 52 weeks) and although the progress has slowed, there is still progress.

- *Why are you working out calves three times a week?*

I would add one, *maybe* two, calve workouts onto your leg day and that's it. Calves are a small muscle that will contribute negligibly to your strength increase.

- *You're working your deltoids in three separate workouts!*

I don't know your specifics but this also seems unnecessary. Work the deltoids on your one day and move on (same as calves).

- *Where are the rest days?*

I like that you've got rest days on Wednesday and Sunday but you mention *only abs*. I do hope you realize that core strength plays a phenomenal role in many workouts. My suggestion is to put two days of rest between upper body workouts and two days of rest between lower body workouts. In other words, if you're squatting Monday, don't deadlift and earlier than Thursday (you can do upper body workouts between this).

The delt workout after delt workout after delt workout is just going to get your muscles exhausted. Any delt workout is going to start targetting chest and arms. Then you work arms, and you're back to chest.

Do abs on your arm day, put some good rest between it and any other compound lift.

- *Are you putting in the work outside of the gym?*

The food you eat, the quality of sleep you get, the stretching/warmups you do, and the lifestyle choices you make (smoking, drinking, career) will all play a role. In a previous post of yours mentioned a high-protein diet, but are you eating enough calories? I don't know your specifics but you probably want to be in the 3000 calorie range: day after day, not just for one day here or there. If you work a demanding job, eat even more.

- *You can't climb forever.*

I purposely built de-loads into my workout. It is impossible to challenge your 1RM each week, every week. I run 12-week progressive overload where week 1 is a lightweight, high rep workout and week 12 is a low rep, high weight workout. After Week 12 I de-load and start back at week 1's light weights (although heavier than the previous Week 1).

---

So, my answer to `Unable to maintain weights and increase in reps from work out session to session, why?` is a combination of poor programming, likely lack of rest + overworked muscles, and potentially diet.